# microsoft chart controls the resource cannot be found

Tags: charts, .net-4.0, controls

Microsoft Chart Controls on shared hosting with .net framework 4.0 installed. "The resource cannot be found."
Locally it works just fine. I confirmed that the dlls are on the server.
I have tried changing all settings in the web.config and ImageLocation parameters. No luck.
Any suggestions?

Comment: A DLL is not a resource.  At least post the exception's stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue first make sure that the chart assemblies are installed in the GAC.

Then try to hit the server with server/yoursite/chartimg.axd?i=0.png&g=0 from the browser (use these exact parameters). If you get  "The resource cannot be found" then the handler is not installed properly: look for the issue in your web.config and try again until you get "System.ArgumentException: The image is not found". This means the handler is installed properly and works as expected.

Then render the page which contains a chart control where Chart.ImageStorageMode = UseHttpHandler. If you get an exception please post the exception stack here as well as your major controls layout like: "the chart is placed in update panel, which is placed in a user control, which is placed in update panel in the page".

Comment: I get "The image is not found." after going to server/yoursite/chartimg.axd?i=0.png&g=0 in the browser which means the handler is installed correctly.

Comment: Further more, Hans is correct, but, the exact error says "HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.". It is a 404. No exception. What am I missing? I have nothing on that page. No update panels. no user controls. Nothing. Only an aspx page with some code behind.

Comment: I tried looking at the code behind again. Nothing I haven't used on that server before. Just the chart object. I thought of image location but then UseHttpHandler would have solved it and it didn't.

Comment: I have concern that it may be a security issue. According your post - everything is ok on your local environment. I suppose you are working as administrator there - so, you have access to all folders and files there. Or your account which you're using for IIS has it. You may also check (and set manually) Temporary Directory for images - here described some common issues - [link]http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2010/06/asp-net-4-0-chart-control-problems-on-iis7.html[link]

Comment: After creating a simple test page with a chart object on it, I managed to get new error messages that actually made sense. Dealing with them solved my problem. Thanks.